# How does Blade @include work with variables?

Tags: php, laravel, include, laravel-blade

I just started working with Laravel / Blade a few weeks ago and was wondering how Blade @include works.

I have a top level index view that then includes some other views. These other views require specific variables, which I know you can pass in through @include.

I also have a controller which creates the top level view. The controller is where I pass in the variables. And it seems that once they've been passed in to the top view, I don't need to pass them in to the sub views.

For a visual

```
controller
    View::make('index', array('abc' => $abc))
index.blade.php
    @include('sub.piece') - Do I still need to pass in the array with abc here?
sub/piece.blade.php
    {{ abc }}
```

Does @include work like other includes where it's essentially a copy paste?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have to pass in data that is already available to the parent view.

Passing data in `@include` is useful for when the variable name differs for the two views.